# Palabras a letras

Tags: python

hay alguna manera de hacer que una lista de palabras se divida para pasarlas por un if una por una

´´´

```
text=[]
fras=set()
texta=str(input("Teclee la frase : "))
textm=texta.lower()
text+=[textm.split]
num=len(text)
print(text)
i=0
while i < num:
    i=i+1;
    if "a" in text:
        fras+=[a()]
    if "b" in text:
        fras+=[b()]
```

´´´

Necesito que al escribir una frase la frase pase por el if de cada letra pero necesito que pasen en orden para formar la palabra al final con cada función, de que manera lo puedo hacer?
Ya que así me agrega todas las letras que encuentra en orden alfabético y después se repite

Comment: Crees que pudieras poner un ejemplo de le entrada que ingresas y la salida que esperas? Seria de ayuda para entender mejor tu duda

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que intentas solucoinar?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres recorrer cada letra de una frase intenta hacer lo siguiente:

```
frase = input('Ingresa una frase: ')
palabras = frase.split()

for palabra in palabras:
    for letra in palabra:
        print(letra)
```

Primero pides al usuario que ingresa una frase, después divides esa frase en palabras con `split()`, después haces un ciclo que va a iterar el numero de palabras en la frase, y por cada iteración de este tenemos otro ciclo que itera por cada letra en la palabra.

Dentro del `for` mas anidado puedes aplicar a cada letra la validación que quieras en este caso yo solo la imprimi.

#### Resultados

Input:

```
Hola Stackoverflow en español
```

Output:

```
H
o
l
a
S
t
a
c
k
o
v
e
r
f
l
o
w
e
n
e
s
p
a
ñ
o
l
```